# Sql - Select Maximum or Minimum value from Selected Column Row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this in oracle sql:

```
H1 Decimal(18,6) ,
H2 Decimal(18,6) ,
H3 Decimal(18,6) ,
H4 Decimal(18,6) ,
H5 Decimal(18,6) ,
H6 Decimal(18,6) ,
H7 Decimal(18,6) ,
H8 Decimal(18,6)
```

And I need to select Maximum / Minimum Value from the table Column not row! it means select the On of (H) with biggest value and return it As MaxH.

Comment: Are the values ever `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `LEAST/GREATEST` here:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8)    AS MinH,
    GREATEST(H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8) AS MaxH
FROM yourTable;
```